# Para que serve a declaração "!important"?

Tags: css

Para que serve a declaração `!important` no CSS?

```
body {
  font-size: 12.5px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

A declaração `!important` serve para forçar o CSS a usar a propriedade descrita nessa linha.

O CSS funciona por hierarquias, uma cascata de regras que obedecem a prioridades. Por exemplo uma propriedade declarada num elemento diretamente no HTML têm prioridade em relação a uma propriedade defenida no CSS. Em casos destes, e em casos de ambiguidade em que duas regras são iguais ou competem, usando `!important` faz essa regra onde ele está presente pervalecer.

Para ser mais específico aqui fica uma lista de prioridades, por ordem crescente (primeiro é menos importante), de como o CSS funciona. E mais uma vez, o `!important` é a exceção que vence todos os casos:

> **Seletores universais**, p.ex: `*{ }`
> **Seletores de *class***, p.ex: `.minhaClasse{ }`
> **Seletor de atributo**, p.ex: `input[type="text"]{ }`
> **Pseudo seletor**, p.ex: `div:hover{  }`
> **Seletor de *ID***, p.ex `#minhaID{  }`
> **No `style` do HTML**, p.ex: `style="color: blue;"`

Esta propriedade `!important` é muito útil, mas é o mesmo que usar "força bruta". Por isso deve ser usada com precaução pois pode criar situações dificeis de fazer debug.

#### Um exemplo simples: http://jsfiddle.net/q48hL/1/

```css
#div1 {
  color: blue;
}

#div2 {
  color: blue;
}

#div3 {
  color: red !important;
}

body > div {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">Teste 1</div>
<div id="div2" style="color: green;">Teste 2</div>
<div id="div3" style="color: green;">Teste 3</div>
```

Repare que o `!important` pervalece até no terceiro caso em que existem regras para esse elemento no CSS e no HTML.

Answer (score 31):

A finalidade o `!important` é sobrepor as **Regras de precedência**.

Exemplo do funcionamento:

**HTML**

```
<p id="a" class="azul">teste</p>
```

**CSS**

```
#a{ color: red;}
.azul{ color: blue !important;}
```

Sem o `!important` ele deveria estar vermelho, pois o `ID` é mais específico que uma *classe*, devido ao uso do mesmo, ele está em azul.

Você pode conhecer um pouco mais sobre *especificidade* e *Regras de precedência* dando uma olhada [neste tutorial](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/specificity_wars.php).