# CSS - Bootstrap min

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Quando abro para edição o CSS do `bootstrap.min` fica uma massaroca sem tabulação.

Tem como resolver isso?

Gostaria de fazer uma simples edição na fonte de uma class e mesmo identificando a linha pela inspeção do navegador, ainda assim é difícil encontrar dentro do .css.

Comment: Baixe o descompactado, que você não terá problemas

Comment: Como seria ele descompactado? Baixei até de novo, mas veio do mesmo jeito. Estou abrindo com o Notepad++.

Comment: Já respondi a sua pergunta. Favor olhar a resposta

Comment: Faz o seguinte Brow, http://jsbeautifier.org/ cola o seu código minificado lá, aperte um botao e seja feliz! ou faz igual todo mundo ai e baixa o arquivo que não esteja minificado.

Answer (score 4):

Marcelo, bootstrap.min significa que é o bootstrap minificado. Minificar um arquivo significa reduzir o máximo possível seu tamanho. No caso, foi eliminado todos os espaços e enters possíveis do arquivo, de modo a reduzir seu tamanho vertical e assim reduzir o tamanho do arquivo original. Isto permite que o browser carregue o arquivo do bootstrap mais rapidamente.

Para baixar o arquivo original e não minificado, você pode acessar o site oficial do bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download.

Answer (score 2):

Esta versão de CSS que você está visualizando é uma 'minificação' do fonte original (note o '-min' no nome do arquivo), por isso lhe parece uma "massaroca"...

Você deve utilizar um formatador de CSS, ou melhor: procure a versão não minimizada.

Comment: Entendi.
Estou com um template da versão "Bootstrap v3.3.1".
Onde consigo baixar essa versão em específico?

Comment: segundo o Google: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.3.1.zip

Comment: Obrigado.
Vou seguindo aqui. Vlw.

Answer (score 2):

Nas [opções de download](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download), você pode escolher por baixar o código fonte e modificá-los de acordo com as suas necessidades.

Se você precisa modificar uma única classe, talvez seja mais simples fazer o uso de [`!important`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25311/4808) nas propriedades que está alterando:

```css
button:last-of-type {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #333 !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button class='btn btn-default'>padrão</button>
<button class='btn btn-default'>customizado</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

É necessário apenas baixar diretamente no `github`, onde se encontra o repositório do `bootstrap`.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Para facilitar mais ainda, aqui vai a versão `raw` do `bootstrap.css` no `github`:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css