# O que é User Agent StyleSheets?

Tags: css, user-agent

Estudando sobre CSS me deparei com o termo *User Agent*, ou folhas de estilo padrão usados pelos navegadores em caso de ausência de folhas de estilos.

- O que é o *User Agent*?
- Cada navegador tem um *User Agent*?
- Existe algum modo de ignorá-los, se sim como?

Vejam na imagem abaixo que por *default* o *Google Chrome* defini o corpo do documento *HTML* com `margin: 8px`;

[image: CSS]

Comment: Precisa que melhora algo?

Comment: A resposta do bigown esclareceu sua dúvida de CSS, mas talvez ainda tenha sobrado um mal-entendido de terminologia. User-agent é o próprio browser, que é quem "age em nome do usuário". Portanto User Agent Stylesheets são as folhas de estilo "nativas" do browser.

Comment: A pergunta indica que não esta(va) claro pra você que user-agent = browser. A resposta não trata disso diretamente.

Comment: @bfavaretto entendi o que quiz dizer. Não quer tentar uma resposta?

Comment: Obrigado, mas acho que a resposta atual + meu comentário já esclarecem para futuros visitantes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Isso indica que foi usado estilo padrão definido no navegador (ou outra forma que está sendo usada para *renderizar* aquele elemento). Ele só é usado se realmente nenhum estilo foi usado nele, mesmo em outros níveis.

Lembre-se que CSS funciona em cascata, um elemento sempre herda as propriedades anteriormente definidas em outro nível. O primeiro desses níveis, que normalmente é sobreposto por um nível mais específico, é o *user agent*, é o padrão do navegador.

A ordem seria:

- User agent style sheets (o navegador)
- User normal style sheets (uma configuração personalizada do usuário)
- Author normal style sheets (você que fez a página)
- Author important style sheets (quando você diz que é [`"important`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25311/101))
- User important style sheets (quando o usuário diz que é `"important`)

Isso [pode ser visto na especificação](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/).

Você ignora esse uso criando um estilo próprio, que é o normal que todo mundo faz.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -3):

Respondendo a sua segunda duvida --> Não existe uma maneira "padrão" de escrever uma sequência de user Agent, então os navegadores usam formatos diferentes, alguns são beeem diferentes, e muitos navegadores da Web colocam muitas informações em seus user agents.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow, o que seria esse Bem Diferente entre um e outro?  Pq eles sai diferentes e não são todos iguais? Vc tem uma fonte? Seria legal vc fundamentar mais sua resposta ;)