# Colorir todo o header

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Preciso alterar a cor do `header` inteiro do site, porem quando aplico o background color no `header`, a cor ocupa apenas o espaço do conteúdo, ficando assim a cor do `body` no topo e em baixo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<body>
    <header class="container-fluid topo">
        <img src="img/selo.png" class="img-fluid mx-auto float-right selo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block mt-4" alt="Logo DoUp">
        <h2 class="text-center text-dark ">Seu curso de espanhol em 12 meses</h2>
    </header>
<div class="meio mt-2">
```

Css:

```
header{
    background-color: #ffc107;
}
```

Como colocar este amarelo para cobrir toda a parte superior?

Comment: @wmsouza n funcionou

Comment: Deve ser alguma `margin` que esta definida, talvez em `.topo`

Comment: em topo n tem nada, uso ele só para .topo img porem mesmo assim n tem margem definidas

Comment: veja se h2 não está com margem, .meio também deve ser alguma margem

Answer (score 1):

Agora que reparei que vc está usando **Bootstrap 4**, então vou reformular a resposta.

Seu problema é que vc está usando as classes `mt-4` no Logo e `mt-2` na div `.meio`

**`mt` na verdade significa `margin-top`**

Para ler a documentação sobre o Espaçamento no Bootstrap 4 leia a documentação aqui: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Já o problema da margem abaixo do `<h2>` é que por default ele tem margens acima e abaixo. Vc pode ler mais sobre esses valores de "CSS Defaults" dos Browsers nessa resposta:  [O que é User Agent StyleSheets?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165937/o-que-%C3%A9-user-agent-stylesheets)* (pesquise sobre user-agent para aprender mais)*

Então basta remover essas classes para resolver seu problema. Veja no exemplo abaixo:

```css
header{
    background-color: #ffc107;
}
h2{
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.meio{
    background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<header class="container-fluid topo">
    <img src="img/selo.png" class="img-fluid mx-auto float-right selo">
    <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="Logo DoUp">
    <h2 class="text-center text-dark ">Seu curso de espanhol em 12 meses</h2>
</header>

<div class="meio ">gdfgfd</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sempre que quiser aplicar uma cor a uma tag de forma generalizada você pode utilizar o nome da mesma dentro do código CSS como se fosse uma ID.
ex.

```
header{
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
```