# Propriedade "all" no CSS. Para que serve e como funciona?

Tags: css

Estava olhando as propriedades CSS e conheci a `all`, só achei ela um pouco confusa.

Sei que a mesma possui 4 estados. São eles: `initial`, `inherit`, `revert` e `unset`. Porém não entendi ao certo como cada um funciona.

### **Dúvidas**

1. Como funciona a propriedade `all` e para que ela serve?
2. Qual o suporte dos navegadores para a propriedade?
3. Existe alguma real utilidade para essa propriedade?
4. Como funcionam os 4 estados da propriedade?

Comment: Boa pergunta, eu já tinha usado all para responder algumas coisas aqui no site, mas não achei nada exclusivamente sobre essa propriedade por aqui

Comment: Pois é, fiquei procurando por uma pergunta relacionada a isso mas não encontrei nada, então resolvi fazer a minha.

Comment: Eu tb acabei dando uma pesquisada pq já tinha usado ela por aqui antes, mas como não tinha nada mais específico sempre vale a pena perguntar!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Como funciona a propriedade all e para que ela serve?

Ela estabelece que valor todas as outras propriedades de um elemento deve ter. É uma forma de simplificar o código e não ter que colocar um valor em cada propriedade.

[Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all).

> Qual o suporte dos navegadores para a propriedade?

O ideal é sempre usar um site que acompanha isso e mostre como está na versões atuais. Por usar o [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=all).

> Existe alguma real utilidade para essa propriedade?

Não, é só comodidade.

> Como funcionam os 4 estados da propriedade?

Note que estas opções não necessariamente são exclusivos da propriedade `all`.

É um pouco confuso e precisaria entender o conceito de herança de valores do CSS.  Eles são valores, mas se comportam como variáveis e seu valor final depende do contexto. Em alguns casos é melhor nem usar se não entender o que está fazendo:

- [initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value) - assume o valor *default*. Este *default* varia de acordo com as regras de herança ([documentação](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial))
- [inherit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit) - assume o valor que foi herdado do elemento anterior ([documentação](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inherit))
- [revert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert) - ele tenta usar o estilo adotado de acordo com [quem foi o responsável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165937/101) por mudar a propriedade.
- [unset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) - será o valor inicial ou herdado de acordo com o que a propriedade foi especificada ([documentação](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inherit-initial))

Exemplo:

```js
$('button:not(.remove)').on('click', function() {
  $('.alltest').css('all', $(this).text());
});

$('.remove').on('click', function() {
  $('.alltest').css('all', '');
});
```

```css
.container {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* inherited */
  
  font-size: 1.5em;
  /* inherited */
  
  text-align: center;
  /* inherited */
  
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /* inherited */
  
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
  /* inherited */
}

.parent {
  color: green;
  /* inherited */
  
  background-color: gainsboro;
  /* not inherited */
  
  width: 80%;
  /* not inherited */
  
  padding: 1em;
  /* not inherited */
  
  border: 5px solid #E18728;
  /* not inherited */
}
/* Styles for Pen, unrelated to all property demonstration */

button {
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>initial</button>
<button>inherit</button>
<button>unset</button>
<button class="remove">remove "all" property</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="alltest">
      <p>Change this div's <code>all</code> value.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/All.js).

[Fonte](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/all/).

Comment: A sua resposta ficou bem clara e com o exemplo pude entender melhor a propriedade!

Answer (score 4):

A propriedade `all` é um *shorthand* (atalho) para pegar todas as propriedades CSS do elemento definidas pelo `user-agent`.

Por exemplo a tag `input` possui alguns atributos CSS que são declarados pelo `user-agent`, se vc quiser "limpar" esses atributos *default* do browser vc pode usar o `all:unset`. Ou se vc tem um `input` estilizado por um folha de estilo externa vc pode usar o `all:revert` para voltar o `input` ao estado *default* do `user-agent`.

***Existe alguma real utilidade para essa propriedade?***

**Pros e contras:** Um utilidade que vejo é que o código CSS fica mais limpo, uma vez que vc vai usar menos linhas de código para remover todos os estilos *default*. Sendo assim, com o `all` vc atinge todas as propriedades de uma vez, e dessa forma vc tem um código mais enxuto, e até sua produtividade pode aumentar. A desvantagem é que vc pode acabar eliminando algum estilo que não gostaria e vai ter que inclui-lo de volta na mão...

Segundo a documentação da Mozilla sobre o assunto: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all

`initial` Especifica que todas as propriedades do elemento devem ser alteradas para seus valores iniciais.

`inherit`: Especifica que todas as propriedades do elemento devem ser alteradas para seus valores herdados.

`unset`: Especifica que todas as propriedades do elemento devem ser alteradas para seus valores `inherited` se herdarem por padrão ou para seus valores `initial`, se não forem.

Resumindo, o `unset` pode voltar para o último valor herdado se tiver algum, se não tiver ele vai para os valores iniciais. No exemplo abaixo, com o `all:unset` o `blockquote` vai herdar os estilos da fonte do `body`, mas se não tivesse nada declarado no `body` o `blockquote` voltaria para a forma `initial`

```css
body { 
  font-size: small; 
  background-color: #F0F0F0; 
  color:blue; }
blockquote { 
  background-color: skyblue; 
  color: red; 
  }
blockquote { 
  all: unset; 
}
```

```html
<blockquote id="quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</blockquote> 
Phasellus eget velit sagittis.
```

`revert`: Reverte o CSS para que uma propriedade assuma o valor que teria se não houvesse estilos na origem do estilo atual (customizado pelo autor ou `user-agent`)

O `revert` é útil para isolar `widgets` ou componentes incorporados dos estilos da página que os contém, principalmente quando usados ​​com a propriedade `all`.

**Importante:** O valor `revert` no entanto tem o suporte dos browser bem mais limitado do que os outros valores como vc pode ver aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert

***Mas para que serve?***

Normalmente se usa o `all` quando vc quer "limpar" estilos *default* do browser para construir o seu próprio estilo, ou quanto vc quer que alguma folha de estilo não incida sobre algum elemento, voltando ele para o estado `initial`.

Veja um exemplo prático:

Limpando o estilo *default* do `user-agent` de um `input`

```css
.input-custom {
  all:unset;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
  <input class="input-custom" placeholder="all unset" type="text">
  <input class="input-custom" type="checkbox" name="" id=""><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="sem all unset">
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
```

***Suporte dos Browser:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Fonte:*** https://caniuse.com/#search=all

Comment: Show de bola Hugo, resposta bem explicativa!

Comment: Valeu jovens, esses assuntos sempre são interessantes para a comunidade e a gente acaba aprendendo tb alguma uma coisinha nova :)

Comment: Adoro o SO justamente por isso, podemos aprender e ajudar ao mesmo tempo!