# Boostrap sobrescrevendo CSS. Como evitar?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Peguei da internet um template pronto em CSS para escolher uma forma de pagamento do meu site. Segue abaixo o link do mesmo.

https://codepen.io/cusx/pen/aNqQdQ

Porém, ao importar o header e o footer, (estou usando PHP para isso) que utilizam Bootstrap, a página de pagamento fica desconfigurada. Ao remover o link do bootstrap a forma de pagamento fica normal, porém como meu header e footer utilizam bootstrap, ficam quebrados.

Tentei criar uma section com um id e colocar antes de todo código css, não obtendo sucesso tentei criar uma div, assim:

Original

```
...
.price h1 {
font-weight: 300;
color: #18C2C0;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}
...
```

Com section id = 'pagamento'

```
...
#pagamento .price h1 {
font-weight: 300;
color: #18C2C0;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}
...
```

com uma div class = 'pagamento'

```
...
.pagamento .price h1 {
font-weight: 300;
color: #18C2C0;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}
...
```

Mas não obtive sucesso.
Também tentei colocar a chamada do meu estilo css antes do link do boostrap, também não funcionou.

Existe alguma maneira de remover o bootstrap em um determinado pedaço do html? Ou de fazer o meu arquivo de estilo sobrescrever? Ou ainda alguma outra forma de poder usar os dois sem que nenhum fique quebrado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duas coisas, a primeira é que as classes que vc quer que sobrescrevam devem vir por último, e não em primeiro, então seria tipo assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="meu-estilo.css" />
```

Ou assim si for o caso.... O importante é que venha após o CSS do Bootstrap.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
    h1 {
        font-family: serif;
    }
</style>
```

**EDIT:**

Vc também pode tentar "resetar" todas as classes inseridas pelo Bootstrap usando um "all:unset" e depois reconstruindo o CSS do seu elemento. Vc pode ler mais sobre essa propriedade aqui [Propriedade all no CSS. Para que serve e como funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/335015/propriedade-all-no-css-para-que-serve-e-como-funciona/)

Então por exemplo seu CSS ficaria assim

```
.price h1 {
  all: unset; /* aqui vc remove os estilos herdados */
  /* agora apenas os CSSs que quer */
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #18C2C0;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.card {
  all: unset; /* aqui vc remove os estilos herdados */
  /* agora apenas os CSSs que quer */
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 520px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

---

**Opção com iframe**

Além disso outra solução seria usar um `<iframe>` Coloque o seu cartão em um iframe e chama ele onde vc  quiser. Assim o CSS do Bootstrap não vai sobrescrever o CSS dos elementos que estão dentro do `<iframe>` Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre o assunto: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Ex: Repare que eu tenho uma Navbar do Bootstrap e no mesmo arquivo chamo um iframe como o exemplo do Codepen que por sua vez não sofre influencia do .CSS indexado do Boostrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul
      
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

  <iframe src="https://codepen.io/cusx/pen/aNqQdQ" style="width:80%;height:300px;" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mesmo colocando o link após, o bootstrap contia sobrescrevendo. Não posso usar iframe, porque eu estou usando o código para modelo do que estou produzindo, e não mara usar o mesmo, então não funciona.

Comment: @RafaelLazzarettiMadalóz cara fiz um **EDIT** e inclui uma solução que pode te atende, acredito que vale a pena vc fazer um teste ai. Leia lá que tem mais detalhes, e no link que citei tb tem mais coisas que podem te interessar.