# Porque está acontecendo esse efeito com a propriedade all?

Tags: css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
    
        html {
            color: red;
            background: blue;
            border: 1px solid white;
        }

        body {
            color: yellow;
            background: green;
            all: inherit;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Esse é um título</h1>
<p>Esse é um parágrafo</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No exemplo de código em cima o `body` herda todos os valores das propriedades do `html` porque a propriedade `all` está definida como `inherit`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
    
        html {
            color: red;
            background: blue;
            border: 1px solid white;
        }

        body {
            color: yellow;
            background: green;
            all: unset;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Esse é um título</h1>
<p>Esse é um parágrafo</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando é alterado o valor da propriedade `all` para `unset` a font do `h1` e `p` é diminuida porque? neste caso o `all: unset` está se comportando como `inherit` e não `initial`, certo? então seria tanto faz colocar `all: inherit` ou `all: unset`, mas esse efeito da fonte um pouco mais pequena não estou entendendo, alguém me explica o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Para mim estão do mesmo tamanho

Comment: Para mim tb, etá tudo do mesmo tamanho, deve ser impressão sua ai

Comment: Não é! realmente os tamanhos estão diferentes vou editar a resposta e colocar um print.

Comment: "resposta" pergunta.

Comment: Cara testei no Chrome e no FireFox, e não houve alteração do tamanho das fontes... Confere se vc não esta dando algum tipo de zoom na janela do browser, ou se não é algum outro tipo de configuração de acessibilidade etc

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda de vocês, se o problema não está acontecendo no computador de vocês deve ser no meu, já tentei de vários jeitos mas continua na mesma, mas vou tentar mais, porque não gosto de ter problemas não solucionados no meu cérebro.

Answer (score 1):

Suas palavras:

> *"Neste caso o `all: unset` está se comportando como `inherit` e não `initial`, certo?"*

Não, errado! Se for `initial` a cor da fonte fica `black`, esse sim é o valor inicial, e não o valor herdado. Se colocar `inherit` ele herda a cor do `html` de qq forma... Esse sim, seria quase a mesma coisa que o `unset`

Um vez que vc coloca `all:unset` no `body`, ele automaticamente herda estilos descendentes do `html`, pois o `body` é filho do `html`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa outra resposta tem mais esclarecimentos sobre o `all` [Propriedade all no CSS. Para que serve e como funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/335015/propriedade-all-no-css-para-que-serve-e-como-funciona/335028#335028)