# Bootstrap tem conflito com meu css. Como fazer hr com texto no meio

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando usar isso para conseguir fazer uma linha horizontal com uma palavra no meio, mas o bootstrap não me deixa usar, ele some com a linha (eu tirei o link do bootstrap que fica no head pra testar se era o problema e funcionou, porém eu preciso dele pra outras coisas do site) Alguém sabe como resolver?

```
fieldset {
    border-top: 1px solid green;
     border-bottom: none;
     border-left: none;
     border-right: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
 }
 
 fieldset legend {
     padding: 5px 10px;
 }

<fieldset>
    <legend>texto aqui</legend>
</fieldset>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen" />
     <!--Fontes-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Klee+One:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>titulo</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header class="head">
        
        <fieldset>
            <legend>TEXTO</legend>
        </fieldset>
        <h1>TEXTO</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        
        <header><h4>vai um monte de texto aqui</h4>
        </header>
            <p>
                lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem
            </p>
            <article>
                <Header><h4>lorem</h4></Header>
                <p>
                    
                   loremloremloremloremloremloremlorem
                </p>
            </article>

        
    </section>
    <footer>
        
    </footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

O Bootstrap está sobrescrevendo seu CSS.

Uma solução para você seria "resetar" a classe inserida pelo Bootstrap usando um `all: unset` e depois reconstruir o CSS do seu elemento.

Seu CSS ficaria assim:

```
fieldset {
     border-top: 1px solid green;
     border-bottom: none;
     border-left: none;
     border-right: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
 }
 
 fieldset legend {
     all: unset; /* aqui você remove os estilos herdados */
     /* aqui apenas os estilos que você quer */
     padding: 5px 10px;
 }
```

Você pode ler mais sobre a propriedade `all` em um post aqui mesmo no Stack: [Propriedade all no CSS. Para que serve e como funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/335015/propriedade-all-no-css-para-que-serve-e-como-funciona/)

Espero ter ajudado.