# Bootstrap4 select transparente

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Implementei um select em uma página utilizando classes do Bootstrap-4 para estilização conforme abaixo:

```
<select class="form-control" name="inputAssunto" id="inputAssunto" required>
   <option>Sugestões e críticas</option>
   <option>Cadastro de marcas e produtos</option>
   <option>Outros...</option>
</select>
```

Eu quero que este componentes receba um background-color transparente, porém já tentei estilizar o componente na classe desta forma e não funcionou. todos os inputs aceitaram a estilização de background, somente este que não.

```
.form-control {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: 0.3 solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

Quando rendererizado o formulário fica desta forma.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero que o select tenha a mesma estilização dos inputs, como fazer?

Comment: Que browser vc está usando? Coloca `background:none !important` e `box-shadow:none !important` para ver se resolve. Se der certo me fala que posto como resposta... Se estiver usando algum componente que não é padrão do Bootstrap diga qual tb pode ajudar a te responder

Comment: Oba, tudo bem? Fiz o teste, não surtiu efeito, o browser é o safari, testei no firefox e o background-transparent funcionou. Mas o seu toque sobre o browser me ajudou a encontrar a solução, tratava-se de algo referente somente ao Safari, então utilizei -webkit-appearance:none; Ai funcionou. Pode colocar na resposta, me ajudou bastante. Obrigado.

Comment: Legal que resolveu então, imaginei que poderia ser algo ligado ao crossbrowser, mas como não tenho Safari aqui não deu para testar. Deixei uma resposta ai, assim a pergunta não fica sem estar respondida, Valeu a força 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é que alguns elementos são estilizados pelo `user-agente`, e para sobrescrever esse estilo as vezes é preciso usar o *vendor prefix* do browser. Vc pode ler mais sobre `user-agent` aqui: [O que é User Agent StyleSheets?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165937/o-que-%C3%A9-user-agent-stylesheets/165942)

Como vc falou que está usando o Safari, para customizar o elemento primeiro vc precisa limpar os estilos desse `user-agent`, para isso vc usa a propriedade `-webkit-appearance:none;`  (**obs:** no caso do FireFox se usaria `-moz-`, IE `-ms-`,  Opera `-o-`)

Então o seu CSS ficaria assim:

```
.form-control {
  -webkit-appearance:none; /* propriedade para limpar estilos do user-agent */
  background: transparent !important;
  border: 0.3 solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```