# Exibição de um progress bar em diferentes navegadores (HTML e CSS)

Tags: html, css, html5

Estou tendo dificuldades em configurar a aparência de um progress bar com css e html

Sou iniciante, estou fazendo meu site agora e me deparei com o seguinte problema: não consigo fazer minha progress bar aparecer direitinho no chrome e firefox. No Microsoft Edge ela aparece da forma que eu quis configurar, mas ao acessar meu index.html no chrome e firefox a progress bar fica diferente. Alguém pode me ajudar?

HTML:

```
<div class="section" align="center">
    <h2><i>Minhas habilidades</i></h2>
    <hr width="200px">
    <h6>Ao clicar, você será direciado ao Wikipedia, onde fala mais sobre cada uma das minhas habilidades</h6>
</div>
<ul class="abilities">
    <!--consegui corrigir com o margin-left-->
    <li>HTML:<br> <progress min= "0" max="100" value="100"></progress></li>
    <li>CSS:<br> <progress min= "0" max="100" value="10"></progress></li>
    <li>JavaScript:<br> <progress min= "0" max="100" value="60"></progress></li>
</ul>`
```

CSS:

```
.abilities{
max-width: 100%;
font-style: italic;
margin-left: 35%;
```

}

```
.abilities progress {
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 2px;
color: rgb(247, 111, 111);
background-color: white;
```

}

Algumas prints do problema:

[image: Microsoft Edge (como eu queria que fosse exibido o progress bar):]

[image: Chrome:]

[image: Firefox:]

Primeira imagem: Microsoft Edge, como eu queria que fosse exibida a progress bar
Segunda imagem: Chrome
Terceira imagem: Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é  um problema de `user-agente` cada browser formata essa tag `<progress>` como "prefere" de  forma que tenha uma  unidade visual mais semelhante ao  próprio browser, te recomendo fazer esse elemento com CSS e HTML,  usando uma  `div` ou um `span`

A vantagem é que já é possível dar semântica a esse artifício usando  `role` e `aria-label` como vc pode consultar aqui e o seu código ficaria assim mais ou menos, com a  garantia de ficar igual em todos os browser! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_progressbar_role

```
<div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">20 %</div>
```

Já o estilo de formatação vc vai ter que usar o CSS...

Aqui é apenas um exemplo, não sugiro usar o Bootstrap para isso, mas é só para vc ver que só com CSS  vc consegue um `progress-bar` totalmente `cross-browser`

Repare como a abordagem deles é bem similar a que citei acima https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/progress/ E repare tb que a `div` de dentro cada um tem as classe `w-75 w-50` e `w-25`, isso significa `75%` de largura, `50%` de largura etc, mas vc pode fazer as classes que quiser, tipo `w-33`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="progress m-5">
  <div class="progress-bar w-75" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress m-5">
  <div class="progress-bar w-50" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress m-5">
  <div class="progress-bar w-25" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre o que é o `user-agent` [O que é User Agent StyleSheets?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165937/o-que-%c3%a9-user-agent-stylesheets)