# Propriedades do css nao fazem efeito bootstrap

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap

galera estou tentando fazer uma coisa simples no css que e mudar a cor da fonte do meu link e as cores estao sendo anuladas por algum motiv que eu nao sei qual e

```
 .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #9d9d9d;
}
```

galera consegi resolver o problema, o erro foi pq carreguei o bootstrap primeiro que a minha folha de estilo

Comment: Poderia também colocar o trecho em HTML?

Comment: Certifica-te que os teus css são importados no html depois dos do bootstrap

Answer (score 6):

Como mencionado pelo @JoãoLuiz, evite usar `!important`, porqu no futuro você pode querer sobrescrever seus próprios estilos, e, além disso, os desenvolvedores que tiverem legado o seu código terão dificuldades para mudá-lo. De acordo com [Stephanie Sullivan [Rewis]](https://twitter.com/stefsull/status/70631020352913408), *designer*, isso é um ato muito egoísta.

Cada seletor no CSS tem um *score*, pontuação ou peso. Quanto mais específico for o seletor, [maior será sua prioridade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25311/para-que-serve-a-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-important), porquanto maior será sua pontuação.

[O `!important` só é recomendado quando alguma classe **deve** ser hard-code](https://zenorocha.com/css-important/), praticamente imutável, só perde para as declarações [inline](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp).

Dessa forma, a melhor forma de sobrescrever o CSS do [Twitter Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) é declarando suas próprias classes e pondo-as depois da inclusão dos estilos do *framework* em questão.

A [melhor forma de fazer isso](https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/) é do seguinte modo:

**Incluir seus estilos**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/seu_css.css">
</head>
```

**Usar os mesmos nomes das classes do Twitter Bootstrap**

```
.container{
    max-width: 50%;  
}
```

Comment: +1 (se interessar, deixei uma referencia aqui no site de como calcular prioridades de seletor http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143893/70 - tem a explicação de como funciona, e link para uma ferramenta de cálculo)

Comment: obrigado por responder acho que o problema causado era pq eu carreguei a bootstrap primeiro que a minha folha de estilo css

Comment: @FernandoAlcantara Ms é exatamente isso que você tem que fazer. Primeiro o Bootstrap e depois seus estilos customizados.

Answer (score 5):

Verifique se no `<head>`o seu `CSS` foi inserido depois do `bootstrap`. As regras são executadas sequencialmente.

Answer (score 4):

Talvez a forma que você colocou o `<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`

ou você pode alterá direto da biblioteca do bootstrap mas a forma que o Guilherme Alvez mencionou pondo o `!important`

Answer (score 4):

Seu CSS deve ser declarado posterior ao bootstrap.

Tente evitar !importants.

Answer (score 2):

Tente:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #9d9d9d !important;
}
```

Tente adicionar `!important` na propriedade `CSS` para forçar o `CSS` a usar a propriedade descrita nessa linha.