# Como sobrescrever alguns atributos do bootstrap?

Tags: css

Peguei um menu da internet que usa o framework bootstrap, quando ele está numa tela maior que 768px a cor do menu inicialmente era cinza claro, eu troquei pra cinza escuro, porém quando a tela é menor que 768px, o menu fica cinza claro novamente, eu precisaria sobrescrever o local que faz o menu voltar pra cinza claro, porém não tenho conhecimentos de como usar a "tag" `@media` (caso seja essa mesmo que eu deva usar). Basta eu colocar no arquivo css algo assim:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top {
        background-color: gray;
    }
```

Ou esse formato está errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30542215/2993657) no Stackoverflow em inglês você tem a lista de todos os media queries utilizados.

A pergunta que fizeram eram quais os breakpoints do Bootstrap 3 e usuário listou todos com comentários. Pegue o código que ele postou adiciona o seu css personalizado dentro das medias queries que gostaria que fossem afetadas.

Comment: Obrigado a todos que ajudaram, todas as respostas foram de ótima ajuda.

Answer (score 5):

Falta os "pontos" em:

```
.navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top
```

Deveria ser assim:

```
.navbar .navbar-default .navbar-fixed-top
```

Não tenho certeza, mas parece que falta um `}` também, deve ficar assim:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top {
        background-color: gray;
    }
}
```

Ainda se não funcionar use o `!important`

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-default .navbar-fixed-top {
        background-color: gray !important;
    }
}
```

Leia quem tem prioridade, é muito importante entender isto:

- [Qual seletor css tem prioridade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143850/3635)
- [Para que serve a declaração "!important"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25311/3635)

Comment: Obrigado a todos que ajudaram, todas as respostas foram de ótima ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Nota que se você quer adicionar o estilo quando a largura for **menor** que 768px, deve utilizar `max-width:768px`. [Aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries) explica detalhadamente as media queries.

Outro fato interessante seria utilizar [`!important`](https://zenorocha.com/css-important/) p/ garantir que adicione o estilo.

Segue um exemplo que adiciona `background-color:gray` quando a `width` for menor ou igual a 600px:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .navbar {
    background-color: gray !important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  navbar
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos que ajudaram, todas as respostas foram de ótima ajuda.