# Centralizar uma tabela (HTML)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Fiz uma tabela no meu `HTML`, mas não consegui centralizar ela no meio da tela.

Ela é vertical e já tentei colocar o `text-align:center` mas não adiantou.

```css
td, th {
  padding: .7em;
  margin: 0;
  /*border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
  text-align: center;
}

th{
  /*background-color: #EEE;*/
}
td{
  font-weight:bold;
  /*background-color: #EEE;*/
}

table{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom : .5em;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table" width="200px" align="center">
          <thead>
              <tr class="status">
                 <th class="cor">Status:</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table" width="200px" align="center">
          <thead>
              <tr class="cliente">
                 <th class="cor">Quantidade</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clientess">
                 <th class="cor">Nº.Pedido</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="fiscal">
                 <th class="cor">Nota Fiscal</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="entprevista">
                 <th class="cor">Entrega Prevista</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pronto. Editei a pergunta

Comment: Mas como você espera que sua tabela fique? Ela esta corretamente representada pelo que você colocou, há varias linhas (`tr`) e em cada linha há um cabeçalho (`th`). Com isso, ela vai ficar da forma que está representada no snippet.

Comment: Espero que ela fique no meio da tela. Ela é uma tabela vertical, e recebe dados do TD de uma API. Só que ela nao fica centralizada no meio da tela

Comment: Mas ela está centralizada... pelo menos é como o que o snippet está.

Comment: Mas quando vejo no chrome, ele nao ta no centro, acaba ficando o pouco pro lado esquerdo

Comment: Pode ser que ela acabe nao ficando centralizada por causa do td que vem depois e aí nao aparece

Comment: @NazareLisboa veja se minha resposta te ajuda

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) serve somente para alinhar o texto de um elemento, por isso ele não é capaz de alinhar a tabela.

A propriedade [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/margin) te permite definir as margens em torno do elemento (um espaço em volta, sendo ele um espaço à esquerda, à direita, ao topo, abaixo ou automaticamente no centro de onde o elemento está contido).

Exemplo:

```
  margin:auto; /* Centraliza sua tabela */
```

No seu caso somente o comando `margin` não adiantará pois as `classes` do `bootstrap` por padrão definem que a tabela ocupará todo espaço permitido, portanto você deve diminuir seu tamanho para que as margens sejam notadas:

```
width: 50% !important;margin: auto;
```

Veja o exemplo abaixo, coloquei bordas vermelhas apenas para tornar o exemplo mais visual:

```css
.table-responsive{
  width: 100% !important;
}

.table {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50% !important; /*Importante manter o !important rs */
    margin: auto;
}

.table-status {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Jquery incluido -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-status">
          <thead>
              <tr class="status">
                 <th class="cor">Status:</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
          <thead>
              <tr class="cliente">
                 <th class="cor">Quantidade</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clientess">
                 <th class="cor">Nº.Pedido</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="fiscal">
                 <th class="cor">Nota Fiscal</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="entprevista">
                 <th class="cor">Entrega Prevista</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou. Voce sabe como consigo deixar um pouco longe a table de status das outras?

Comment: Adicionei uma classe para a tabela de status `.table-status` e coloquei uma margem acima e abaixo dela. Era isso que você queria, se alguma das respostas  atendeu sua necessidade peço que sinalize marcando como correta.

Comment: Exatamente! Voce pode me tirar uma dúvida? Quando o TD da table é formado, as TD's vêm da API que eu puxo, elas acabam flutuando um pouco pra cima, sabe o motivo?

Comment: É difícil concluir sem ver como o código funciona, o que eu faria para analisar é `inspecionar` o elemento pelo navegador para ver como está o `CSS`, caso você não consiga resolver desta forma sugiro a abertura de uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Certo. Me tira outra dúvida do teu código? Para que serve o "!important"?

Comment: Resumidamente força o css a obdecer, definindo uma prioridade para determinada instrução, veja:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25312/88202

Comment: Certo. Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Use a seguinte classe como classe pai para tudo o que quiser centralizar na tela.

```
    .poscentralized{

       -webkit-display: flex;
       display: flex;
       -webkit-align-items: center;
       align-items: center;
       -webkit-justify-content: center;
       justify-content: center;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma das possíveis soluções para centralizar a tabela seria definir no `CSS` as margens esquerda (`margin-left`) e direita (`margin-right`) da tabela com valor `auto`:

```css
.table{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Coluna 1</td>
    <td>Coluna 2</td>
    <td>Coluna 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Nao funcionou. Pode ser que seja pq to fazendo no bootstrap

Comment: @NazareLisboa Isso deve estar ocorrendo porque no código `CSS` do `bootstrap` já deve haver alguma uma definição de margens para a tabela, o que está gerando um conflito de definições `CSS`.

Comment: @Leandro está certo, pois, basta abrir o bootstrap.min.css que você verá que tem estilo para table, porém não sei se atenderá sua necessidade Vou postar o que encontrei na minha resposta abaixo

Answer (score -2):

Vai no CSS de defina:

```
.table{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Ou também você pode colocar:

```
.table{
margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: 50%;
}
```

Mas dependendo de sua aplicação, o segundo método pode não funcionar direito. Recomendo o primeiro método que é mais direto, e funciona melhor.

Answer (score -3):

consegui eu so mudei isso depois de table e ela centralizou em html.



  
  
   BEM VINDO AO CARISMA! 


**
  
     linha 1 coluna 1 
     linha 1 coluna 2 
     linha 1 coluna 3 
  
  
     linha 2 coluna 1 
     linha 2 coluna 2 
     linha 2 coluna 3 
  
       
        linha 3 coluna 1 
        linha 3 coluna 2 
        linha 3 coluna 3 
   
   
      linha 4 coluna 1 
      linha 4 coluna 2 
      linha 4 coluna 3