# Como deixar o rodape com posição relativa e no mínimo no final da página?

Tags: html, html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Estou usando em várias páginas o position sticky do html5 para dar um efeito no menu do site.

Mas tem páginas que o conteúdo interno é muito pequeno, não ocupa nem 150px de altura e acontece que não posso usar o rodapé com `position fixed` pois cobriria muito conteúdo nas outras páginas, por ter muita informação nele.

Então o que gostaria de fazer é um tipo de `min-bottom` assim como o `min-height`.

Utilizo bootstrap 4 beta para o front-end. Alguma dica?

[image: nessa página preciso que]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu também tenho esse problema. A solução que uso é usar [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceitos_Basicos_do_Flexbox), um novo recurso do CSS3.

Basicamente, assim:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body > .main-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/** Estilos opcionais. */

.main-header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
}

.main-content {
  padding: 20px;
}

.main-footer {
  background-color: #333;
  border-top: #303030;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <header class="main-header">
      Seu cabeçalho.
    </header>
    <div class="main-content">
      Seu conteúdo principal.
    </div>
    <footer class="main-footer">
      Seu footer.
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

No mais, se não estiver satisfeito com a proposta acima, deixo [outras opções](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/).

Comment: Vc testou se o flex não irá quebrar o grid do bootstrap?

Comment: Bom dia amigo. ontem não respondi que estava estudando ainda, vou testar hoje, mas pelo que vi na documentação do próprio bootstrap 4 incorporaram o flexbox. Pelos exemplos, vai dar certo sim, segue o link para alguém que use também: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/                                    
                                                                                                             E muito obrigado!

Comment: Testado. Seu código só funciona sozinho sem as classes do bootstrap, infelizmente, mas com o código do próprio bootstrap funciona se utilizar `height: inherit` herdando a altura 100% do `html` e `body`. Valeu.

Comment: Olá. Creio que se o problema for sobrescrita de CSS, você pode usar a diretiva `! important`. Para saber mais, veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25311/para-que-serve-a-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-important).

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é usar jQuery para que o rodapé fique sempre no *bottom*. Se a altura do rodapé *couber* na tela, ele ficará sempre no *bottom*, caso contrário ele ficará após, acompanhando normalmente os outros elementos.

**Veja:**

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
   let prev_h = $("#rodape").prev("*").outerHeight(true),
       prev_o = $("#rodape").prev("*").offset().top,
       foot_h = $("#rodape").outerHeight(true),
       prevoh = prev_h+prev_o,
       foot_m = 30; // margem superior do rodapé
       
   if(window.innerHeight - prevoh - foot_m < foot_h){
      $("#rodape").css({
         "top": prevoh+foot_m +"px",
         "bottom": ""
      });
   }else{
      $("#rodape").css({
         "top": "",
         "bottom": "0"
      });
   }
});
```

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

#rodape{
   background: yellow;
   position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <h2>Header</h2>
         Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. Mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin. Ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor. Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat.
      </div>
   </div>
</header>

<main>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
       <div class="col col-lg-2">
         1 of 3
       </div>
       <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
         Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. Mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin. Ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor. Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat. Adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum.
       </div>
       <div class="col col-lg-2">
         3 of 3
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col">
         1 of 3
       </div>
       <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
         Variable width content
       </div>
       <div class="col col-lg-2">
         3 of 3
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</main>

<div id="rodape">
      <h2>Rodapé</h2>
      Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. Mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin. Ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor. Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat. Adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum. Morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. Tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra. Eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus. Fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim. Purus in massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium. Aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris. Mauris sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum. Vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse. Et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce. Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet.
</div>
```