# Aumentar tamanho do do textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

Estou tentando usar o [Sweet Alert 2](http://www.sacheprofessional.com.br/js/sweetalert2-master/example/).

Gostaria de aumentar o campo do textarea usando o atributo rows, mas não está funcionando.

Como faço para aumentar o tamanho do campo?

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  telaModal()
});
function telaModal(){

        swal({
            title: 'Dados do acidente',
            html:
            '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Data do Acidente">' +
            '<textarea id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input" rows="100"></textarea>',
            focusConfirm: false,
            customClass: 'sweetalert-lg',
            onOpen: function() {
                $('#swal-input1').datetimepicker({
                    "format": 'd/m/Y',
                    "mask":true,
                    "value": new Date()
                });


            },
            width: '400px',
            heightAuto: false,
            preConfirm: () => {
                return [
                    document.getElementById('swal-input1').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input2').value
                ]
            }
        })


    }
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.25.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<button class='btn' >Clique</button>
```

Gostaria que ficasse mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classe "swal2-input" do seu componente possui um height pré-setado.

Você pode tanto eliminar a classe do seu html:

```
'<textarea id="swal-input2" rows="100"></textarea>',
```

Quanto adicionar um height:auto, para poder utilizar o rows como definidor do tamanho:

```
'<textarea id="swal-input2" style="height:auto!important" class="swal2-input" rows="100"></textarea>',
```

Sendo que segundo a documentação a classe para textarea é a swal2-textarea, porém mesmo com ela o rows não funciona.

Comment: E com isso perderia o bootstrap `form-control` né?

Comment: Com a segunda alternativa você pode manter a classe swal2-textarea lá. Quanto a form-control, não há nenhuma menção ao bootstrap tanto no seu codigo, quanto na sua pergunta. Não entendi a sua citação ao mesmo.

Comment: É que, por padrão parece que ele formatado em bootstrap, ai quando eu tirei a class `swal2-input` ele não ficou formatado como antes

Comment: Pode deixá-la, contanto que adicione style="height:auto!important" para que o tamanho do textarea fique de acordo com o rows. Dessa forma o estilo usado na classe swal2-input permanece, exceto o height.

Comment: Entendi. Realmente deu certo. Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

A classe `swal2-input` está sobrepondo as `rows` com um `height`, e isso provavelmente vem da `lib` que você está usando, para resolver basta acrescentar uma nova classe e setar um `height` para ela como `!important`...

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  telaModal()
});
function telaModal(){

        swal({
            title: 'Dados do acidente',
            html:
            '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Data do Acidente">' +
            '<textarea id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input text-area"></textarea>',
            focusConfirm: false,
            customClass: 'sweetalert-lg',
            onOpen: function() {
                $('#swal-input1').datetimepicker({
                    "format": 'd/m/Y',
                    "mask":true,
                    "value": new Date()
                });


            },
            width: '400px',
            heightAuto: false,
            preConfirm: () => {
                return [
                    document.getElementById('swal-input1').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input2').value
                ]
            }
        })


    }
```

```css
.text-area {
  height: 10em !important;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.25.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<button class='btn' >Clique</button>
```

Comment: Pra que serve o `!important` mesmo?

Comment: Basicamente é para sobrepor as Regras de precedência. Pode ver mais detalhado aqui [Para que serve a declaração “!important”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25311/para-que-serve-a-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-important) - @adventistaam

Comment: Blz! Muito obrigado!