# FullCalendar no Modal do Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar

Estou usando o fullcalendar no modal do Bootstrap, porém o as cores do dia da semana ficam brancas, mas quando tiro o cursor para fora do site, as cores ficam pretas. Vejam:

Quando o cursor está dentro da área do site, a cor fica branca:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o cursor saí da área do site, como por exemplo colocar sobre a barra de endereços do navegador, a cor da fonte volta a ficar preta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei alterar diretamente no CSS, mas não deu certo, vejam:

```
#calendario{
  display:none;
}
.fc-ltr .fc-basic-view .fc-day-top .fc-day-number {
    float: right;
    color: #000;
}

.fc-unthemed thead,.fc-day-header, .fc-widget-header, span{
    color: black;
}
```

O jQuery está dessa forma:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            height: 250,
            contentHeight: 273,
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: false,
            eventColor: '#dd6777',
            color: '#000'
          });
        });      
        $('#calendario').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('render');
        });

        $("#button").on("click",function(){
        $("#calendario").modal(open).show();;
        });
   </script>
```

Tem algum meio de corrigir isso?

Comment: Tente colocando `!important` na frente do valor, tipo: `color: #000 !important;`.

Comment: Perfeito Sam! Funcionou!! Muito obrigado mais uma vez!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!important` para forçar a declaração da propriedade ([veja este tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25311/8063)):

```
.fc-ltr .fc-basic-view .fc-day-top .fc-day-number {
    float: right;
    color: #000 !important;
}

.fc-unthemed thead,.fc-day-header, .fc-widget-header, span{
    color: black !important;
}
```

Ao usar `!important` após o valor da propriedade, irá evitar que outros blocos de estilos alterem a propriedade do elemento, sejam regras com mais força ou pseudos-classes (como `:hover`, por exemplo).